# Xcode error while openning file

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

Today i tried to open .xcworkspace file on my project but i got some error like this

```
Process:               Xcode [740]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.2 (6776)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6776000000000000~11
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       811890240
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [740]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-04-07 13:45:47.945 +0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C1514)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        97BA685B-5788-8D8E-FA49-9E2A21F38165


Time Awake Since Boot: 7300 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
DVTUndoManager for delegate:<IBStoryboardDocument 0x7f7f5cb6a200>
ProductBuildVersion: 6C131e
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): enableUndoRegistration: IBDocumentUndoManager 0x7f7f6616fe50 is in invalid state, enableUndoRegistration may only be invoked with matching call to disableUndoRegistration

UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: DVTUndoManager for delegate:<IBStoryboardDocument: 0x7f7f5cb6a200>
```

[image]

I also reinstalled xcode again and clear catch but it didn't work out.
Anyone know how to fix this? 
Thanks!

Comment: seems like your error is here :UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): enableUndoRegistration: IBDocumentUndoManager 0x7f7f6616fe50 is in invalid state, enableUndoRegistration may only be invoked with matching call to disableUndoRegistration. My suggestion would be to open DVTUndoManager.storyboard (or wherever you got that class) and try to remove problematic IBStoryboardDocument.

Comment: I would just uninstall it and re-install it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in his case, open with right Click on **.xcworkspace *** & click on - Show package Content & then Remove unnecessary things from that opened folder & then try to open again  **.xcworkspace**, you will successfully open it.

Comment: What unnecessary things is that? I have 2 folders and 1 contents.xcworkspacedata

Comment: Other files.. @KrisJulio

Comment: Define "unnecessary things" please

Comment: means that things which is not important to you. so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If above answer did not fix your issue as it did not in my case.

Follow the below steps to fix this issue,(Note:- this will have the Autolayout issues, which you can fix easily)

1. Edit your storyboard as Source code.
2. Locate useAutolayout="YES", change its value to useAutolayout="NO" and save the file.
3. Now open the Storyboard in Interface Builder mode.
4. You will be shown a pop up dialog with message "The document "Main.storyboard" had xx internal inconsistencies that were found and repaired".  click on show details and copy and save the "contrain ids(object ID)" in different file.

   "This constraint is not in the referencing constraints for its first item []: object ID Fo7-pW-aKi

   This constraint's [object ID ElL-p9-pfY] second item is not in the document

   This constraint's [object ID FQa-9e-EhA] second item is not in the document

   This constraint is not in the referencing constraints for its first item []: object ID WPb-Rv-3fE

   This constraint's [object ID 1oW-wk-Zzu] second item is not in the document

   This constraint is not in the referencing constraints for its first item []: object ID 5Px-Ng-H66

   This constraint is not in the referencing constraints for its first item []: object ID iKL-sX-B40

   This constraint's [object ID 6EU-Hv-AiV] second item is not in the document

   This constraint's [object ID ElL-p9-pfY] second item is not in the document

   This constraint's [object ID FQa-9e-EhA] second item is not in the document
   "
5. Click on "OK" button.
6. The storyboard is loaded successfully.
   7.Now again open the storyboard in Source code mode. now find and delete all the "contrain ids(object ID)"(saved in step 4) and then save the file.
7. Now open the Storyboard in in Interface Builder mode. it opens successfully without any issue but in locked mode(u won't be able to modify anything)
8. To unlock storyboard choose a locking level from the Editor > Localization Locking menu and choose Reset Locking Controls.this will unlock the storyboard.
9. Fix some of the auto-layout issues and you good to go.